# Wrong resolution on Eyefinity 3x monitor setup

Tags: amd-radeon, eyefinity

I have 3 perfectly the same monitors Philips 49" connected to my AMD R9 290 OC VGA ( 1 on DVI, 1 on HDMI to DVI adapter and 1 to HDMI port ).
While not in Eyefinity mode - everything seems to be fine - each monitor works on 1080p in extended desktop mode.
Anyway when I switch to Eyefinity - instead of 5760x1080 it switching to 5760x1068.
I've noticed that the third monitor under Eyefinity is switching to a lower resolution ( x1068 )

- What could cause the wrong resolution and how to fix it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author was using a bad HDMI cable.

Comment: So.. If someone have an issue because of a problematic hardware, and it is quite possible to help someone else with such problem - it is an off-topic ?! Great logic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.
The problem was with the HDMI cable of the 3rd monitor when I replaced it the problem was solved.
It is working as expecting now.